# Null Checking Nested Method Calls in Java

Tags: java, syntax, error-handling, null

I need to null check nested method calls like so:

```
if (getShopModel() != null && getShopModel().getType() != null)
```

I don't think this is the best way to do it though as I am calling getShopModel twice which could be quite expensive.

Is there a better way to check getShopModel().getType() in such a way that I only need to call getShopModel() once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a variable...

```
Model model = getShopModel();
if (model != null && model.getType() != null)
```

This costs you nothing, saves an extra call, and might even make it easier to debug should you be interested of the value returned by 'getShopModel'.

Comment: Excellent! The ugliest thing about Java is the long, incomprehensible strings of method calls it seems to breed.

Comment: @Gene, yeah, I hate those too. They look clever, but debugging them is hell. But there are coding styles that explicitly resent them, such as the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).